# Probability of choosing two cities C++

Tags: c++, probability

I'm making a program where I have a list of 34 cities and I am wanting to give each of these cities a probability of being chosen.

So I have:

```
vector<float> vec;
int s;
    cin >> s;
    srand(s);
    for (int k=0; k < 34; k++)
    {
    float p1= (float)rand()/(float)((unsigned)RAND_MAX+1);
    vec.push_back(p1);
    }
```

So that gives each city a probability. The problem I am now having is I want to then do a random number generator that will choose two of these cities. So, for example city1 will have a 5%, city2 a 2%, city3, a 3%, etc. How can I randomly choose two of these cities based off the probabilities given?

Comment: "So that gives each city a probability" It does? From what I see that loads 34 random floats between 0 and (RAND_MAX/(RAND_MAX+1)). How does *that* assign probability to *anything* ? What is your *real* question? Is it how to produce a random selection from a *weighted* set of probabilities? Have you looked at [`std::discrete_distribution`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/discrete_distribution) ?

Comment: What you're trying to do is quite unclear. Your code stuffs a random probability into a vector, one entry for each city it appears. Then you're saying you want probabilities to be defined, not random. Which is it?

Comment: Are the numbers produced actual probabilities or relative probabilities? It seems like they are relative since you have no check that the total `<= 100`

Answer (score 5):

I did this in genetic algorithm.
for your cities consider a line of 10 units.
now from 0-5 units on line are city1 6-7 for city2 and 8-9 for city3.
now choose a number at random from 0-9.
and found out in which cities range it comes in.

Comment: Assuming they are relative probabilities.

Comment: Still kinda confused from your response. Can you give an example of this?

Comment: RaNdoM_PoWneD explained it well

Answer (score 1):

At first glance my solution will be :

- Create a number equals to all city's probability
- Create a random number, with max random number is equal to the previous number
- Take the random number, and go throught your city vector and take the one who is corresponding.

Example :

```
City 1 : 5%
City 2 : 8%
City 3 : 2%
City 4 : 5%
City 5 : 12%

Create a number -> Number a = 32 (5+8+2+5+12)

Generate a number with : 1 <= number

Assume that the number is equal to 12

City 1 is choose if : 1 <= number <= 5 (So not)
City 2 is choose if : 6 <= number <= 13 (So yes)

City 2 is choose.
```

If you have any questions about that, you are welcome :)

**Edit** :

Well i will give you some more explaination.

Take this code :

```
for (int k=0; k < 10; k++)
{
    float p1= (float)rand()/(float)((unsigned)RAND_MAX+1);
    vec.push_back(p1);
}
```

Assume now that vec contain the following informations :

```
5
3
8
5
12
14
8
5
6
18
```

With each number correspond to the probability to choose a city.

> ```
> 5 -> 5% probability to choose (City1)
> 3 -> 3% probability to choose (City2)
> 8 -> 8% probability to choose (City3)
> ... etc
> ```

Now i will give you some code and i will explain it :

```
int nbReference = 0;
for (auto it = vec.begin() ; it != vec.end() ; ++it)
{
   nbReference += *it;
}

nbReference = rand(nbReference);

int i = 0;
int cityProbability = 0;
for (auto it = vec.begin() ; it != vec.end() ; ++it)
{
   cityProbability = *it;
   if ((i + cityProbability) > nbReference)
   {
      return (i + 1);
   }
   i += cityProbability;
}
```

First i create a number equals to the addition of all city's probability

```
   int nbReference = 0;
    for (auto it = vec.begin() ; it != vec.end() ; ++it)
    {
       nbReference += *it;
    }
```

Second, i generate a number that is respect the following range -> 0 < nbReference

Third, i create a loop that take all city one by one and quit when we got right city.

How does we know when a city is good?

Let's take an example!

With our previous probability

> 5 3 8 5 12 14 8 5 6 18

NbReference is equals to (5+3+8+5+12+14+8+5+6+18) so 84

To each city we are going to put a range equals to his probability plus all of previous city's probability. Let me show you :

```
    5 -> Range 0 to 4  (0 to 4 = 5 ---> 5%)
    3 -> Range 5 to 8  (5 to 8 = 3 ---> 3%)
    8 -> Range 9 to 17 
    5 -> Range 18 to 22
    ... etc
```

If the number that we create here

```
nbReference = rand(nbReference);
```

Is in a city range, so that city is choosed.

Example : If the number is 16, city3 is choosed!

```
    5 -> Range 0 to 4  Number is 16 so NOPE
    3 -> Range 5 to 8  Number is 16 so NOPE
    8 -> Range 9 to 17 Number is 16 so YES!
    5 -> Range 18 to 22
    ... etc
```

Does is this helpfull? :)

Any questions? You are welcome

Comment: you can create a simple for loop and calculate the cumulative probability as in your example. If the number is smaller than you have the correct one, stop searching and return that city. I.e.

Comment: Can you give a code example of this? I am still not seeing it. Sorry :/

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this code can help you (follows partially WhozCraig advice)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    using namespace std::chrono;

    system_clock::time_point tp = system_clock::now();
    system_clock::duration dtn = tp.time_since_epoch();

    std::default_random_engine generator(static_cast<int>(dtn.count()));

    //Generate 34 cities

    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> gen_distribution(0,1);

    auto getProb = std::bind ( gen_distribution, generator );

    std::vector<double> citiesProb;

    double probSum(0.0);
    double cityProb(0.0);

    for (int k=0; k < 34; k++)
    {
        cityProb = getProb();
        probSum += cityProb;
        citiesProb.push_back(cityProb);
    }

    //Pick 7 cities

    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> pick_distribution(0,probSum);

    auto pickCity = std::bind ( pick_distribution, generator );

    double chooseCity;

    double probBasket;

    for (int k=0; k < 7; ++k)
    {
        probBasket = 0.0;
        chooseCity = pickCity();
        for (int i = 0; i < citiesProb.size(); ++i)
        {
            if (chooseCity >= probBasket && chooseCity < probBasket + citiesProb[i])
            {
                std::cout << "City with index " << i << " picked" << std::endl;
            }
            probBasket += citiesProb[i];
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

How it works:

```
city1 5%(0.05), city2 25%(0.25), city3 8%(0.08), city4 10%(0.1)
```

then

```
probSum = 0.05 + 0.25 + 0.08 + 0.1 = 0.48
```

then choose a number between 0 and 0.48 (named pickProb) and

```
if pickProb is between 0 and 0.05 pick city1 (prob = 0.05/0.48 = 10%)
if pickProb is between 0.05 and 0.30 pick city2 (prob = 0.25/0.48 = 52%)
if pickProb is between 0.30 and 0.38 pick city3 (prob = 0.08/0.48 = 16%)
if pickProb is between 0.38 and 0.48 pick city4 (prob = 0.1/0.48 = 20%)
```

if probSum = 1.0 then city1 is picked with probability 5%, city2 is picked with probability 25% and so on.